# Room initial query very slow

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have room database with a simple query in its dao

```
SELECT * FROM entries
```

But it takes about 10 seconds to finish when the app is first launched. It becomes fast after this initial run.
Is there a way for me to fix this?

PS: my room database contains a prepackaged database, so I'm guessing that the slow process due to copying the database but can i by pass this?

Comment: how big is the size of the database? and what do you mean by pre-packaged, does it ship with the app or you are copying it over the wire?

Comment: Its about 117mb and its saved in the asset folder to be copied by the database

Comment: Room copies your DB file 117mb and 10 seconds is look like fast. What about create something like splash screen when db not ready to avoid feeling that query too slow ?

Comment: I did something similar. I showed an information dialog which delays the user for a bit